# Converting a string with a leading special character into a double?

Tags: java

I'm at the beginning of my Java journey, and have run into a little problem that I'm having a little difficulty figuring out.

```
// Buffered Reader - Cost Per Employee

    BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Cost per employee?");
    CostPerEmployee = in3.readLine();
    CostPerEmployeeD = Double.parseDouble(CostPerEmployee);
    System.out.println("Each employee costs $" + CostPerEmployeeD +".");
```

I am looking to be able to convert the string input into a double even if it contains a leading "$" character. I am currently running into a NumberFormatException.

Unsure of how to utilize try, catch, and finally statements (if they're at all applicable here).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact value of `CostPerEmployee` and how long is this string? Please [edit] your question to include the full complete exception/error message you get.

Comment: Look into `DecimalFormat("$#")` and consider using BigDecimal for money calculations ( `.setParseBigDecimal(true)` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's [String class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) offers many methods for manipulating strings.  One such method is the [replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) method, which allows you to replace all instances of one string with another.  This method takes 2 arguments, the target string and the replacement string.  You can remove the target string by simply passing an empty string for the replacement string.  For example:

```java
"$123.5".replace("$", "")
```

Would produce:

```java
"123.5"
```

Using this, we can update your code by adding only one method call:

```java
BufferedReader in3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Cost per employee?");

// Notice the call to replace() on this line:
CostPerEmployee = in3.readLine().replace("$", "");

CostPerEmployeeD = Double.parseDouble(CostPerEmployee);
System.out.println("Each employee costs $" + CostPerEmployeeD +".");
```

Please note that `CostPerEmployee` and `CostPerEmployeeD` are not defined in the code block you provided, and you have not handled the IOException thrown by the readLine() method.  I am assuming that this code block is from a larger program, where these problems are resolved.  In the future, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help clear these things up.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @Christian No problem!  If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting and marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static double convertToDouble(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return Double.NaN;

    str = str.trim();
    str = str.startsWith("$") ? str.substring(1) : str;

    return str.isEmpty() ? Double.NaN : Double.parseDouble(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Truth is you actually cannot directly convert `String` like this `$22.33` to a `Double` like.

You have to get rid of that dollar (`$`) sign. For that that you can either use `String` helper methods `replace` or `substring`.

```
String costString = in3.readLine();
Double costDouble = Double.parseDouble(costString.substring(1));
```

or

```
String costString = in3.readLine();
Double costDouble = Double.parseDouble(costString.replace("$", ""));
```